# Codeception bootstrap failing

Tags: php, codeception

Installing Codeception via a .phar works well, but I've decided I want to move all of my dependancies into composer.  When I try to bootstrap codeception, this is my error:

```
(dev) stagl [/var/www/dev] (master) > vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap

Initializing Codeception in /var/www/dev

File codeception.yml created <- global configuration
tests/unit created <- unit tests
tests/functional created <- functional tests
tests/acceptance created <- acceptance tests
tests/unit.suite.yml written <- unit tests suite configuration
tests/functional.suite.yml written <- functional tests suite configuration
tests/acceptance.suite.yml written <- acceptance tests suite configuration
tests/_bootstrap.php written <- global bootstrap file
Building initial Guy classes
Building Guy classes for suites: unit, functional, acceptance
CodeGuy includes modules: CodeHelper
CodeGuy.php generated successfully. 1 methods added
TestGuy includes modules: Filesystem, TestHelper
TestGuy.php generated successfully. 12 methods added
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CERTINFO - assumed 'CURLOPT_CERTINFO' in /var/www/dev/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Configuration.php on line 189
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/dev/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/dev/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:29
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /var/www/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:892
PHP   6. Codeception\Command\Bootstrap->execute() /var/www/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/dev/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Bootstrap.php:80
PHP   8. Codeception\Command\Build->execute() /var/www/dev/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
PHP   9. Codeception\Configuration::modules() /var/www/dev/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Build.php:77
WebGuy includes modules: PhpBrowser, WebHelper
WebGuy.php generated successfully. 47 methods added

Bootstrap is done. Check out /var/www/dev/tests directory
```

What I find strange is that this works with the phar, but not like this?  I most certainly have curl enabled in my php-cli settings:

```
(dev) stagl [/var/www/dev] (master) > php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Codeception would not work properly using an older version of Zend Server.  I uninstalled this and a newer copy of php5.4 and things are now working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 7 or 8 then try below command (Just replace the '\' instead of '/' ):

```
vendor\bin\codecept bootstrap
```